# Label text is not updating based on what is chosen in the select

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/XMc6t/

The label's text should update depending on what is chosen in the select's options. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<label id="amount" name="amount">Test</label>
<select name="cycle" id="cycle">
    <option>Monthly</option>
    <option>Annually</option>
</select>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(

function () {
    $('#cycle').change(

    function () {
        var rate = 0;
        if (('#cycle option:selected'.text() == "Monthly")) {
            rate = 2;
        } else {
            rate = 5;
        }
        $('#amount').text('$' + rate);
    });
});
```

Comment: I just want to point out that you don't need to type `$(document).ready(...)`. The modern equivalent is `$(function(){});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems

- In the fiddle jquery was not inlcuded
- Instead of using the text of the selected element, you can easily replace it with the select's value
- And other syntax errors

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cycle').change(function () {
        var rate = 0;
        //check the value of the select element
        //missing $ before your selector
        if ($(this).val() == "Monthly") {
            rate = 2;
        } else {
            rate = 5;
        }
        $('#amount').text('$' + rate);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GwSBN/)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle, but the actual error was in the line:

```
if (('#cycle option:selected'.text() == "Monthly")) {
```

it should be:

```
if ($('#cycle option:selected').text() == "Monthly") {
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XMc6t/1/)**